# How to break very long string in table?

Tags: php, html, css

I have similar code

```
<table width="1024" height="768">
<tr>
<td>
<? echo $description; ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But $description is very long string, and it break my design, width of table increases. How can I divide my string with transfer into next row? PHP or HTML, CSS

Comment: use word wrap with `php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo wordwrap($description, 100, "<br />\n");
```

more info about [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Answer (score 2):

As diEcho said, you can use the PHP function [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php). To wrap `$description` to 80 characters, for example, you'd use:

```
<?php echo wordwrap($description, 80, ' ', true); ?>
```

This tries to cut up `$description` into 80 character segments, separated by the space character. The browser should wrap text around the space character.

If you're going to wrap this way, you probably want a design where sizes are specified in `em` or `px` (given you know the font's size). Otherwise, your arbitrary wrapping number may not work at different zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS like this:

```
<td>
<div style="word-wrap:break-word"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
</td>
```

It allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line without adding a space or any other character.

Answer (score -1):

ideally not using tables for layout?

other than that try using the table{table-layout: fixed;}

Comment: The same thing happens with long text (not separated by whitespace) in divs, spans, etc. CSS3 adds the word-wrap property (http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/), but not all browsers support all CSS3 features yet.